# Text fields will Display/hide Based on Drop down Select ed value even when navigated to back after click on search

Tags: javascript, jsf

i have a Drop Down it contains 5 items in it,if i select first one few text fields will display like so on..

at first based on drop down text fields will working fine but when after clicking on search and navigating to back page text fields not displaying according to the drop down value.

Please help me with even after navigating to back it should display correctly.
and i have tried this code.

**Jsf Code For Drop down:**

```
 <h:outputText value="Report Type " />
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{customReportBean.reportType}" id="reportTypeField"
onchange="reportType()">
<f:selectItem itemValue="alerts" itemLabel="Alerts" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="violations" itemLabel="Violations" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="events" itemLabel="Events" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="threats" itemLabel="Threats" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="callhistory" itemLabel="Call History" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="msghistory" itemLabel="Message History" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Java script:

```
<script>
function reportType() {


if(type == 'alerts') {
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:alertsFilterPanel').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:violationsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:eventsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:ucThreatsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:callHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:msgHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
} else if(type == 'violations') {
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:alertsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:violationsFilterPanel').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:eventsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:ucThreatsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:callHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:msgHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
} else if(type == 'events') {
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:alertsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:violationsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:eventsFilterPanel').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:ucThreatsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:callHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:msgHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
} else if(type == 'threats') {
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:alertsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:violationsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:eventsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:ucThreatsFilterPanel').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:callHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:msgHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
} else if(type == 'callhistory') {
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:alertsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:violationsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:eventsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:ucThreatsFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:callHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('custom-report-form:msgHistoryFilterPanel').style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>
```

Search Button code:

```
<h:commandButton id="reports_search_filter_search" value="Search" action="#{customReportBean.showSearch}"/>
```

after Clicking on search will navigate result page then if i navigate to this main page text fields not displaying according to drop down value.

Thanks.

Comment: Use ```localStorage``` for selected text

Comment: its not about text bro ,for example in the drop down i have values like vehicle ,and mobiles .if i select vehicle it should display the text fields like vehicle number ,vehicle color ,and if i select mobile vehicle fields should hide and then it should display mobile related content like mobile name ,mobile price.
at first if i select mobile it will displaying mobile related field and if i click in apply or search it navigates to result and i am navigating back it displaying vehicle related text fields but drop down value is mobile.
thanks bro anyway for tried. @HidaytRahman

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Also read [ask] and edit the question to make it understandable. Maybe add a description of the desired and the real behaviour.